# How transform this mcrypt php code to the same code in nodejs?

Tags: php, node.js, mcrypt

I need to transform this php code :

```
$cipher_alg = MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES;
$key = "thekey";
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher_alg, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher_alg, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

return base64_encode($encrypted_string);
```

to nodejs.

I tested using https://github.com/tugrul/node-mcrypt but with the same string, the crypted result is not the same :

Code nodejs tested :

```
let blowfishCfb = new MCrypt('tripledes', 'ecb');
let iv = blowfishCfb.generateIv();
blowfishCfb.validateKeySize(false);
blowfishCfb.validateIvSize(false);
blowfishCfb.open('thekey', iv);

let ciphertext = blowfishCfb.encrypt(text);

return Buffer.concat([iv, ciphertext]).toString('base64');
```

Can you help to understand this ?

Thank,

Comment: Wow, a combination of four poor security choices: Triple DES, ECB mode , Blowfish and null padding! Also note that ECB mode does **not** use an IV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not concat the IV and the cypher together :

```
let blowfishCfb = new MCrypt('tripledes', 'ecb');
let iv = blowfishCfb.generateIv();
blowfishCfb.validateKeySize(false);
blowfishCfb.validateIvSize(false);
blowfishCfb.open('thekey', iv);

let ciphertext = blowfishCfb.encrypt(text);

return ciphertext.toString('base64');
```

Comment: ECB mode does not use an IV so there is no point in creating one.